Setting input/ouput channel of @Gateway and @ServiceActivator dynamically using Spring EL or property placeholders
The annotation @MessagingGateway allows defaultRequestChannel to be set using the property placeholder ${}:
@MessagingGateway(defaultRequestChannel = "${gateway.request.channel}")
public interface MessageGateway {

    @Gateway(requestTimeout = 2000)
    void sendListing(List<Path> entries);
}

But I cannot to similar on the @Gateway annotation:
@MessagingGateway
public interface MessageGateway {

    @Gateway(requestTimeout = 2000, requestChannel = "${gateway.request.channel}") // invalid
    void sendListing(List<Path> entries);
}

Similarly I cannot dynamically set inputChannel/outputChannel of ServiceActivator using the properties placeholder or SpEl.
Do I need to resort to configuring a ServiceActivator manually using ServiceActivatingHandler?

The property placeholder was never worked on those annotations. Original such a feature was only a part of XML configuration. Although that is indeed possible very easy with Java & DSL configuration, the annotation evolution has left behind. The @MessagingGateway was introduced a bit late and such a resolveEmbeddedValue was requested of its attributes.
I wonder what really difference for the application logic that would make if those channel names would be dynamically resolved from properties.

For me it would make it easier to insert a transformer between a MessageGateway and ServiceActivator for example. I'd just need to modify the channel names in the properties and create a new Transformer bean, or indeed have this available in a different profile. So Spring EL is available with DSL or XML? I've only just started investigating Spring integration and it seems this might be one place I'd have a preference to use XML configuration if I can use SpEL or the DSL.

The Java DSL is based on whatever you can do with regular @Bean definition, and indeed propertie placeholder can be used there via @Value on the bean method argument. Stil not clear why would one do that non-obvious configuration instead of routing, for example.

That's a simple to answer; I'm still early in my study of Spring integration so looks like routing is next on the list!
